# Meaning of "was having", "had" and "have had" in English

Tags: sentence-construction, tense, sentence-meaning, past-tense

How to tell someone that I have observed fast full day?

> 1 I was having fast whole day
>
> 2 I had fast today
>
> 3 I have had fast today

I feel all are correct to say

Please, help me to understand the meanings of the above sentences.

Comment: *Have fast* is ungrammatical, so that should be addressed before we discuss the question of past progressive, simple past, or present perfect.

Comment: But what if I wanted to use fast as a *noun*? Should I use *have a fast* or *keep a fast*, or other use? None of the answers explain it.

Comment: @LucianSava I would start by *not* using it as a noun...

Comment: @snailboat, Thank you for your comment! Maybe someday I'll ask here the reason if I don't get myself the answer.

Answer (score 5):

None of these options are particularly grammatical.

The most common versions would be to say:

> I fasted today.

This is a simple statement of fact.

> I was fasting today.

This implies that you *were* fasting but are not any more.

> I had to fast today.

This says that something required that you fast today.

> I have had to fast all day.

This says that you've been doing it for a while and *can* (but does not necessarily) imply that you are no longer doing this action.

Answer (score 1):

"I fasted the whole day" is fine for now.
If you provide more context the answer may vary.

- 1) Having fast doesn´t sound correct because "having" is used when
  you are receiving/experiencing something (having classes, having
  trouble...), and you cannot receive fasting, you do fasting.
- 2) and 3) are not correct, because "had" is used for past tense, and
  "today" is still going on. "I have been fasting today" would be
  correct in that case.
  Hope it helps!

Comment: Your bullet point number two is incorrect. "I have had **to** fast today" is a perfectly grammatical statement. The past tense is implying that the fasting is in the past, not that the day is in the past.

Answer (score 0):

None of these.
The right way to say 
"I have fasted." OR
"i have been fasted." OR
" I have observed the fast today. "

Comment: "i have been fasted." - it is definitely incorrect